# Deploy Next js 13 On cPanel

Tags: deployment, cpanel, next.js13, nextjs-dynamic-routing, app-router

I hope you are doing well. I am currently experiencing a challenge in deploying my project on cPanel using the new app router feature. Would anyone have any suggestions on how to accomplish this task?
i'm using app router